# Why :contains(text) select all <i> tags?

Tags: jquery

expection: to choose elements that contains "Conon" and "Nikon" **ONLY**

fact: chose not only the elements I want, but also all `<i>` tags, dynamic created elements.

confusion: How does it chose `i`?

Here are my codes:

```js
$(function() {
  var $category = $("ul#toggle li:gt(6):not(:last)");
  $category.hide();
  $(".showMore > a").click(function() {
    $category.show();
    $(this).text("not all brand")
      .css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(":contains('Canon'),:contains('Nikon')").addClass("promoted");
  });
});

var $elementDom = $("<div></div>");
$elementDom.text("createdDivElement");
$("body").append($elementDom);
var $textDom = $("<div>This is a text div</div>");
$("body").append($textDom);
var $attrDom = $("<div id='attr'>This is a attr div</div>");
$("body").append($attrDom);
```

```css
#toggle li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.showMore {
  text-align: center;
}

.showMore a {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}

.promoted {
  color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="toggle">
  <li><a href="#">Canon</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sony</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">samsung</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nikon</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Panasonnic</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">other Brand</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
</ul>
<div class="showMore">
  <a href="#"><span>show all brand</span></a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: what if I change `$(":contains('Canon'),:contains('Nikon')").addClass("promoted");` to  `$("li:contains('Canon'),li:contains('Nikon')").addClass("promoted");`? 
I suppose that texts inside `<li>` will all turn greenyellow, but only texts inside `<i>` tag changed. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because you're using the `:contains` selector with no element context, therefore jQuery is looking at *every element* and checking if it matches the `:contains` selector.

In turn, the higher level elements, such as `body`, will match this so the class is then applied to the `body` and the text color of all child elements is affected.

To fix this, make the `:contains` selector more specific, eg `a:contains`:

```
$("a:contains('Canon'), a:contains('Nikon')").addClass("promoted");
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".showMore > a").click(function() {
    $(this).text("not all brand").css("background-color", "yellow");
    $("a:contains('Canon'), a:contains('Nikon')").addClass("promoted");
  });
});

var $elementDom = $("<div></div>");
$elementDom.text("createdDivElement");
$("body").append($elementDom);
var $textDom = $("<div>This is a text div</div>");
$("body").append($textDom);
var $attrDom = $("<div id='attr'>This is a attr div</div>");
$("body").append($attrDom);
```

```css
#toggle li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.showMore {
  text-align: center;
}

.showMore a {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}

.promoted {
  color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="toggle">
  <li><a href="#">Canon</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sony</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">samsung</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nikon</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Panasonnic</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">other Brand</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
</ul>
<div class="showMore">
  <a href="#"><span>show all brand</span></a>
</div>
```

*Edit* - or putting the class on the `li` as your comment suggests works fine too, you just need to amend the CSS rue slightly for it to have enough precedence to override the default `a` styling:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".showMore > a").click(function() {
    $(this).text("not all brand").css("background-color", "yellow");
    $("li:contains('Canon'), li:contains('Nikon')").addClass("promoted");
  });
});

var $elementDom = $("<div></div>");
$elementDom.text("createdDivElement");
$("body").append($elementDom);
var $textDom = $("<div>This is a text div</div>");
$("body").append($textDom);
var $attrDom = $("<div id='attr'>This is a attr div</div>");
$("body").append($attrDom);
```

```css
#toggle li {
  display: inline-block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.showMore {
  text-align: center;
}

.showMore a {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
}

.promoted,
li.promoted a {
  color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="toggle">
  <li><a href="#">Canon</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sony</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">samsung</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nikon</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">Panasonnic</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
  <li><a href="#">other Brand</a><i>（30440） </i></li>
</ul>
<div class="showMore">
  <a href="#"><span>show all brand</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: what if li:contains("Conon")? @RoryMcCrossan